# pandas: How to calculate yearly inflation from monthly data?

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe with mensal inflation, it has a PeriodIndex:

`inflation
month

2016-01       1.27
2016-02       0.90
2016-03       0.43
2016-04       0.61
2016-05       0.78
2016-06       0.35
2016-07       0.52
2016-08       0.44
2016-09       0.08
2016-10       0.26
2016-11       0.18
2016-12       0.30
2017-01       0.38
2017-02       0.33
2017-03       0.25
2017-04       0.14
2017-05       0.31
2017-06      -0.23
2017-07       0.24
2017-08       0.19
2017-09       0.16
2017-10       0.42
2017-11       0.28
2017-12       0.44`

I thought that the yearly inflation would be very easy to calculate, just resample to a yearly period:

```
(df/100+1).resample('A').cumprod()
```

but it gives me the error:

```
AttributeError: 'PeriodIndexResampler' object has no attribute 'cumprod'
```

It works with simpler functions, like sum, but I tried some alternatives and cumprod doesn't aggreate the results.

My expected answer for would be:

```
2016    1.062881
2017    1.029473
```

**Which is the best way to do this calculation?**

Here is the data for copy and paste:

`python
[[Period('2016-01', 'M'), 1.27],
 [Period('2016-02', 'M'), 0.9],
 [Period('2016-03', 'M'), 0.43],
 [Period('2016-04', 'M'), 0.61],
 [Period('2016-05', 'M'), 0.78],
 [Period('2016-06', 'M'), 0.35],
 [Period('2016-07', 'M'), 0.52],
 [Period('2016-08', 'M'), 0.44],
 [Period('2016-09', 'M'), 0.08],
 [Period('2016-10', 'M'), 0.26],
 [Period('2016-11', 'M'), 0.18],
 [Period('2016-12', 'M'), 0.3],
 [Period('2017-01', 'M'), 0.38],
 [Period('2017-02', 'M'), 0.33],
 [Period('2017-03', 'M'), 0.25],
 [Period('2017-04', 'M'), 0.14],
 [Period('2017-05', 'M'), 0.31],
 [Period('2017-06', 'M'), -0.23],
 [Period('2017-07', 'M'), 0.24],
 [Period('2017-08', 'M'), 0.19],
 [Period('2017-09', 'M'), 0.16],
 [Period('2017-10', 'M'), 0.42],
 [Period('2017-11', 'M'), 0.28],
 [Period('2017-12', 'M'), 0.44]]`

Comment: What is expected output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='A')).cumprod()
```

Comment: **This doesn't work** Weirdly if I run with sum() it correctly gives me the aggregate value, but if I run with cumprod() it returns with a value for each month. It looks like pandas doesn't treat cumprod() as a aggregate function.

Comment: @neves - Yes, it is expected, it return same size series like original DataFrame. sum, mean aggregtae data, `cumsum`, `cumprod`, `diff` not.

Comment: So maybe need first use `sum` like and then for output `Series` [`cumprod`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumprod.html)`df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='A')).sum().cumprod()`